# MS Access VBA Looping through records and back to the start again

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba, do-while

I'm trying to find the most elegant solution and hoping someone can help.

What I need to do is select the next item in the recordset, but if it gets to the end I want it to go to the beginning. I suppose round-robin style. I'm having trouble with the loop, it'll work just fine until the last record then it continuously returns the first record.

The idea here is that the user can double click on the control (in this case Listbox named lstAttendees) and it will cycle through the available values. The values are basically Yes, No, N/A etc but the list is dynamic and can change which is why I don't want to hard-code it.

Relevant code as follows. Where I write to debug window is where i'd insert my sql appropriately, this is just for testing for the moment:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
stQry = "SELECT * from List_AttendanceType"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(stQry)

Do While Not rs.EOF
    If rs!Attendance = lstAttendees.Column(3) Then
        rs.MoveNext
        Debug.Print rs!Attendance
        If rs.EOF Then
            rs.MoveFirst
            Debug.Print rs!Attendance
        End If
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

I'm sure the solution is simple enough but I'm not seeing it with fresh eyes.

**EDIT/UPDATE**
Well as fate would have it I figured it out 5 minutes after posting here, but I will keep this open for anyone else to reference. The code which works is as follows, it was just a matter of bailing out of the sub.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
stQry = "SELECT * from List_AttendanceType"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(stQry)

Do While Not rs.EOF
    If rs!Attendance = lstAttendees.Column(3) Then
        rs.MoveNext

        If rs.EOF Then
            rs.MoveFirst
            Debug.Print rs!Attendance
            Exit Sub
        Else:
            Debug.Print rs!Attendance
        End If
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand why you do this. I understand that you want to select the record coming just after the one that user has double-clicked , and if the clicked record is the last one, select the first one in your table. If that's correct, your adapted code  won't do it. You have 2 mistakes: When you find the record the user clicked on with `If rs!Attendance = lstAttendees.Column(3)` what you are doing is a first `movenext` (which is correct) but then if you are not at the end of your  recordset you do a another `movenext` and you continue looping.

Comment: continuing... So, Mistake 1 : you jump over 1 record by doing 2 `movenext`. Mistake 2 : You never do an `exit sub` unless you are at the `EOF`.  If my understanding is correct, I can rewrite your sub correctly but I'd like a confirmation

Comment: Thanks @ThomasG - perhaps I can explain a little more what the purpose of this is. It's used in monthly meetings where there are a set number of expected attendees, however the nature of life means not everyone can make it for whatever reason, and we need to log their attendance accordingly. I needed to use a listbox for this because using dropdowns on a subform excludes members who have left this regular meeting for another one, or left the company, and the historical data if shown in a subform just shows a blank record on their name. Using the listbox gives me more control over what to show.

Comment: The purpose of doing the loop is so the host can double click the members who are not present and cycle through the reasons (List_AttendanceType) values which are then inserted into the attendance record. It's quicker than opening up a separate form for each one.